# for loop attaches wrong variable to output from pascal compiler to MIPS generator (I'm programming in Java)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, mips, pascal

I'm trying to do some code generation from Pascal to MIPS (via programming in Java). I'm currently just working on initializing the MIPS integer values. The code I've programmed to initialize the variables is:

```
   for (StatementNode sn : statements) {
            VariableNode var = null;
            ValueNode value = new ValueNode("0");
            if (sn instanceof AssignmentStatementNode) {
                AssignmentStatementNode asn = (AssignmentStatementNode) sn;
                for (VariableNode vr : vars) {
                    var = vr;
                if (asn.getExpression() instanceof ValueNode) {

                        value = (ValueNode) asn.getExpression();
                        break;
                    }

                }
                answer += var.getName() + ":   .word   " + value.getAttribute()
                        + "\n";
            }
        }
```

Based on the pascal code:

```
program assignSt;
var one, two, sum : integer;
begin
one := 1;
two := 2;
sum := one + two
end
.
```

It should be outputting:

```
.data
one:   .word   1
two:   .word   2
sum:   .word   0
```

but instead I'm getting

```
.data
one:   .word   1
one:   .word   2
sum:   .word   0
```

I've been programming all evening and I'd really like some fresh eyes on the problem. All help is much appreciated. I'm using QtSpim for my MIPS assembly(version 9.1.9) and Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Juno service release 2).

Comment: It would help if you named the tools you used and their version.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to answer my own question, however, I decided to take a different approach which involves a lot less code. Here's the answer I came up with, if anyone's curious:

```
public String writeCode(DeclarationsNode node, CompoundStatementNode node1) {
        ArrayList<VariableNode> vars = node.getVars();
        ArrayList<StatementNode> statements = node1.getStatements();
        VariableNode var = null;
        String answer = "";
        for (StatementNode sn : statements) {
            ValueNode value = new ValueNode("0");
            if (sn instanceof AssignmentStatementNode) {
                AssignmentStatementNode asn = (AssignmentStatementNode) sn;
                for (VariableNode vr : vars) {
                    var = vr;
                    if (asn.getExpression() instanceof ValueNode) {
                        if (asn.getLvalue().getName().equals(var.getName())) {
                            value = (ValueNode) asn.getExpression();
                            answer += var.getName() + ":   .word   "
                                    + value.getAttribute() + "\n";
                            var.setDone(true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!var.isDone()) {
                        answer += var.getName() + ":   .word   "
                                + value.getAttribute() + "\n";
                        var.setDone(true);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the line that increments `answer` up inside the prior loop, before the 'break' statement. At present you're using a stale value for `var.` In fact you don't need the `var` variable at all: just use `vr.`